# Synchronise ArrayList over two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to synchronise an ArrayList over two threads. Basically, I want one thread appending objects to the list and the other one reading from that list at the same time.

Here is the class that deploys the threads:

```
public class Main {
    public static ArrayList<Good> goodList = new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new GoodCreator());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new WeightCounter());
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Then the two Runnable classes:

This one reads lines of two values from a text file and appends new objects.

```
public class GoodCreator implements Runnable{
    private ArrayList<Good> goodList = Main.goodList;
    private static Scanner scan;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread 1 started");
        int objCount = 0;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "//Goods.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
            synchronized(goodList){
                goodList.add(new Good(Integer.parseInt(words[0]), Integer.parseInt(words[1])));
                objCount++;
            }
            if(objCount % 200 == 0) System.out.println("created " + objCount + " objects");
        }
    }

}
```

This iterates over the arraylist and is supposed to sum up one of the fields.

```
public class WeightCounter implements Runnable{
    private ArrayList<Good> goodList = Main.goodList;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread 2 started");
        int weightSum = 0;
        synchronized(goodList){
            for(Good g : goodList){
                weightSum += g.getWeight();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(weightSum);

    }

}
```

No matter the input, weightSum never gets incremented and stays 0

```
Thread 1 started
Thread 2 started
0
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You can use `ArrayBlockingQueue` instead. Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html

Comment: Must you use ArrayLists? How about a queue from the concurrent library?

Comment: This isn't a reproducible example...

Comment: @YassinHajaj  That's what makes concurrency bugs so hard to find:  They often are not reproducible.  In this case, there is an obvious data race between the two threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something called a producer-consumer task. You can do it with arraylist, but it's honestly just not the right way to approach this problem.

Luckily, Java provides us with some collections, the BlockingQueue collections, which are designed specifically for this reason;

```
//the collection with the stuff in it
static BlockingQueue<Object> items = new BlockingQueue<Object>();
//(there are a few different types of blocking queues, check javadocs.
//you would want Linked or Array blocking queue

//what happens on the reader thread
public void producer()
{
    //read the data into the collection
    for (all the data in the file)
    {
       //add the next item
       items.put(/* next item from file or w/e */);

       //stop if necessary
       if (atEndOfFile) stillReadingData = false;

       //etc
    }
}
```

Now you need to read the data out of the queue - luckily this is easy enough;

```
//what happens on the other threads
public void consumer()
{


   //keep this thread alive so long as there is data to process
   //or so long as there might be more data to process
   while (stillReadingData || !items.isEmpty())
   {
       //get the next item from the list
       //while the list is empty, we basically sleep for "timeout" timeunits,
       //then the while-loop would repeat, and so on
       Object o = items.poll(long timeout, int units);
       if (o != null) //process it
   }
}
```

In this way, you can continuously add items to the queue with the producer thread, and the items will be processed as soon as a consumer thread is free (this approach scales well with lots of consumer threads). If you still need a collection for the items, then you should make a second collection and add them to that after they have been processed.

As a side note, you may still need to synchronize oprations which occur while processing the items. For example, you would need to synchronize increments on "weightSum" (or alternately use AtomicInteger).

Answer (score 2):

You are running two independently running threads.  These thread can run in any order and if one stop e.g. to read from a file, the other thread doesn't assume it has to wait for it.

In short, your second thread completes before the first thread has added anything to the list.

There is no good fix as this is not a good example of why you would use multiple threads, however to get an outcome what you can do is this.

```
public class WeightCounter implements Runnable{
    private ArrayList<Good> goodList = Main.goodList;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread 2 started");
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           try {
               Thread.sleep(100);
           } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
               throw AssertionError(ie);
           }
           int weightSum = 0;
           synchronized(goodList){
               for (Good g : goodList)
                    weightSum += g.getWeight();
           }
           System.out.println(weightSum);
        }
    }
}
```

This will print the sum 10 times, 0.1 seconds apart. Depending on how long your file takes to load you will be able to see the sum for what has loaded so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change in the `WeightCounter` class.

```
public class WeightCounter implements Runnable{
   private ArrayList<Good> goodList = Main.goodList;
   @Override
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Thread 2 started");
      int weightSum = 0;
      while(goodList.isEmpty()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
      synchronized(goodList){
        for(Good g : goodList){
            weightSum += g.getWeight();
        }
     }
     System.out.println(weightSum);
   }
}
```

This change will cause the `WeightCounter` thread to wait for the other thread to finish populating the `goodList` with data before attempting to read from it.

Comment: Your example has two problems:  1) It does not wait for the other thread to _finish_ populating the `goodList`:  It waits for the other thread to _start_ populating it.  2) It accesses `goodList.isEmpty()` without synchronization.  When thread A updates some variable (e.g., the length of the list) there is no guarantee of when (or even _IF_) thread B will be able to see the change unless _both_ threads are using some kind of synchronization.

Comment: 1. Agreed. The example is only to provide the questioner with some headway and is not representative of how proper multithreaded code should be written. 2. Synchronizing on `goodList` in the while loop will lead to another problem: deadlock which is why I omitted it and try block for the `InterruptedException` that could be thrown.

Comment: You don't need (or want!) to be synchronized on the lock while sleeping, but if the thread that is polling the length does not synchronize on the lock while fetching the value from memory, then the Java Language Specification does not require the thread to ever see length > 0, no matter how many items the other thread adds to the list.  Of course, in most JVMs, the polling thread _will_ see length > 0, but the point is, you can't call the program correct unless it is correct for every JVM behavior that is permitted by the spec.